# C# incorrect output

Tags: c#, output

This is my code, its purpose it to enter number of students, then ask each student for their name and each student enters 5 marks... My problem is that when I run the code, for example, if I enter 2 students , it asks for their name but then asks for their mark 10 times instead of 5. So it is outputting the total times to enter the mark instead of the 5 for each student, how do I fix this?

```
        int total = 0;
        int gt50Count = 0;



        Console.WriteLine("How many students are there?");
        int students = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int y = 1; y <= students; y++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();


            for (int ask = 1; ask <= students; ask++)
            {


                for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
                    int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");

                        int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        mark = newmark;
                    }
                    total += mark;

                    if (mark >= 50)
                    {
                        gt50Count++;
                    }
                }
            }



        }
        Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);

        double average = (total / 5) * 1.00;
        Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);

        Console.WriteLine("Greather or equal to 50 count = " + gt50Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are 3 `for` loops, the second one is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have  nested loop over student, once again.

```
 for (int ask = 1; ask <= students; ask++) //why this loop ?
 {
    ..
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)  // 2 x 5 = 10
    {
       .... //ask for mark 10 times
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra for loop in there that simply needed to be removed. Also, I'm assuming you're wanting to get the sum and average for each student entered. To do that, you'll need to include that functionality at the bottom of your first for loop. Check out this refactored code:

```
 int total = 0;
 int gt50Count = 0;

 Console.WriteLine("How many students are there?");
 int students = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 for (int y = 1; y <= students; y++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter student name");
     string name = Console.ReadLine();

     for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
         int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         if (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");

             int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             mark = newmark;
         }
         total += mark;

         if (mark >= 50)
         {
             gt50Count++;
         }
     }

     Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);

     double average = (total / 5) * 1.00;
     Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);

     Console.WriteLine("Greather or equal to 50 count = " + gt50Count);
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```